# Is there a way to run a javascript specifically only on small size (mobile) devices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am trying to run a javascript only on mobile phone using Foundation and Rails, (and haml, this is haml example, but don't pay attention to that).

I am doing something like this:

```
.row
 =# something for large screens
    .row.show-for-small-only
      .small-10.small-centered.columns
        = javascript_tag "$('.someClassIPointTo').myfunction();"
```

So I am trying to run this javascript only for small size screens, and NOT for large screens. Is there a way for doing that other then duplicating the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my own question, and here it goes:

I have added a class `.my_indicator_class inside` `.show-for-small` class. Something like this (haml example):

```
.show_for_small
 .my_indicator_class
```

And then in my javascript code I have used it to check whether this element is visible, like this:

```
var isVisible = $('.my_indicator_class').is(":visible");

if(isVisible){
  //My code that will run only for small screens
}else{
  // Code for big screens :)
}
```

And whola, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript to detect whether the device is mobile or not and then, run the code you want.

```
if( (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) &&
    (window.innerWidth < SCREEN_WIDTH) && (window.innerHeight < SCREEN_HEIGHT) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

Source: [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Comment: Well that depends on the mobile devices. I am more concentrated to check for small sized screens. But I might have some answer, hm, I will try it and I will post an answer

Comment: You can also check the size of screen and add a condition to the if statement.

Comment: I am using foundation. Is there something that I can use that already exists there? `.show-for-small-only` or something like that?

Comment: I dont know about Foundation, but I added in the condition of small screen size.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like to check based on type of the device, also I cant check for screen width as it can be different